# What should I do to prevent my kiwi leaves losing their color?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, vines, fruits, kiwifruit

My kiwi leaves are losing their green color too fast. Even new, small leaves can lose it and fall off.

The kiwi is 1 year old, grown in a pot in my apartment. It is not close to a window or a radiator.

What should I do to prevent this from happening?

[image]

Comment: Can you add more information, such as how long you've had the plant, and whether its growing in the ground or in a pot. If in a pot, how big is the pot and what did you use as a planting medium?

Comment: I have updated text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving the kiwi 1m from corner.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like [spider mite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_mite) damage. Look for small white 'grains' or 'specs' on the undersides of the leaves. If you find them, then you have a spider mite infestation. Use a light soap and water mixture at about weekly intervals until the spider mites clear off.

[Here's a good link](http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn7405.html) from the University of California's Integrated Pest Management program, for detailed information on control/management procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Are the roots too wet?  Has it been fertilized?